# Codeigniter Change loaded language

Tags: php, codeigniter

Currently i have a language loaded inside MY_Controller which extends CI_Controller. But inside a special page which controller (let's call it ABC controller) extends MY_Controller, I need to override the loaded language with another language. I tried loading another language inside this ABC controller, but unsuccessful. Is there a way to unload the loaded language and load another language?

Comment: Check the answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31895341/codeigniter-dynamic-language-functionality/41661355#41661355

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>Have you tried just loading the language file you need?</del>

```
$this->lang->load('filename', 'language');
```

<del>It should be then accessible just like your default language.  I haven't tested this tho, but from my understanding this should be the way to go about it.</del>

Reference: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html

---

**REVISED**

I ended up digging a bit more for you, and found that you CANNOT load a default language (define it as default in your controller) and then later try to change it to something else.

Follow these steps:

- If you need a language OTHER than english (default), set that in your config.
- If you want to load ANOTHER language on a controller basis, you need to define that (most commonly in your `constructor` using something like session array / user selection.
- You cannot load 2 languages (1 in the constructor, then another in a different class.. won't work!)

Reference here per forum posts: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/176223/

Comment: yes, i have loaded the default language (English) inside MY_Controller which is extended by other controllers. I tried loading a secondary (Chinese) language hoping it will override the English language inside this ABC controller which also extends MY_Controller, but still, only the English language is accessible.

Comment: I have updated my answer, looks like you need to fix your controllers, cannot declare 2 languages in 1 controller (or a controller you extend).

Comment: Cool thx. I figured i just need to implement another optional param to my MY_Controller constructor to determine which language to load. That should work for my case. Thx for the effort!!!

Answer (score 19):

an easier way is to reset the language data and is_loaded

```
$this->lang->is_loaded = array();
$this->lang->language = array();
```

Comment: how to change to english or other lang...??

Answer (score 7):

I know it's a bit late to answer this but I think you can change the config item 'language' dynamically based on page requirement.

```
$this->config->set_item('language', 'chinese');
$this->config->set_item('language', 'english'); // based on the language folder of course holding language files
```

I had a requirement to send newsletters in users base lang, and this helped me change the language on the fly, hope this might help..

Comment: Works for me :D ... This should be the accepted answer, I believe, coz it's the easiest solution out of all the answers given.

Comment: That is the way to do it, and it is never to late for the right solution!

Answer (score 4):

I encounter this problem and find a tricky solution.

```
$this->lang->load('text', 'english');
echo $this->lang->line('__YOUR_LANG_VARIABLE__');

//CI will record your lang file is loaded, unset it and then you will able to load another
//unset the lang file to allow the loading of another file
if(isset($this->lang->is_loaded)){
    for($i=0; $i<=sizeof($this->lang->is_loaded); $i++){
        unset($this->lang->is_loaded[$i]);
    }
}

$this->lang->load('text', 'chinese');
echo $this->lang->line('__YOUR_LANG_VARIABLE__');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is the only working solution when working with language files that have the same keys

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you have any application installed built in `codeigniter` and you want add a language pack, just follow these steps:

1. Add language files in folder `application/language/arabic`
  (I added arabic lang in sma2 built in ci)
2. Go to the file named `setting.php`
  In
  `application/modules/settings/views/setting.php`
  you will find the array:

```
<div class="controls">

    <?php /*

  $lang = array (
      'english' => 'English',

      'arabic' => 'Arabic',  // +++ Add this line

      'spanish' => 'Español'
```

Now save and run the application.